# kendoWindow does not pop up a window in a subpage normally

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

In my `child pages`, the use of Bootstrap’s `navigation monitoring` templates, at the same time there are a number of the kendoGrid and other pop-up window, the question now is, when I click the button pop-up window, this window will **run to the top of the child  page**, and **then locate the current position**, the experience is very poor, my colleague also encountered similar problems, but he is to use the attributes of the `position`, is solved, but my problem is still there, I think my problem is that the reason of the `navigation bar`.

Look at this Gif：

[image]

Here is my relevant code:

```js
function openAttachmentWin(attachmentType) {
        var win = $("#attachmentWindow1").data("kendoWindow");
        var attachId = basicInformation.model.employeeCode;
        win.refresh('${base.contextPath}/xxpub/xxpub_attachment.html?id=' + attachId + '&attachmentType=' + attachmentType);
        win.open();
    }


    $("#attachmentWindow1").kendoWindow({
        width: "700px",
        height:"500px",
        title: '<@spring.message "附件上传"/>',
        modal:true,
        resizable: false,
        visible:false,
        iframe:true,
        position:{
            top: 3000, //No matter how you change it, it won't work, so I don't think that's the problem.
            left: "20%"
        }
    });
```

```css
    body {
        position: relative;
    }

    ul.nav-pills {
        top: 20px;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
    div.col-sm-10 {
        height: 250px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    #content {
        /*height: 250px;*/
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .nav-pills > li.active > a, .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus, .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover {
        background-color: #3dc5ff;
    }


    @media screen and (max-width: 810px) {
        #section1, #section2, #section3, #section4, #section5,
        #section6,#section7,#section8,#section9,#section10,
        #section11,#section12,#section13,#section14
        {
            margin-left: 130px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-2" id="myScrollspy">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#section1">基础信</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">薪酬信息</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">基本信息</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section4">工龄信息</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section5">工作经历</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section6">教育信息</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section7">职称信息</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section8">技能证书</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section9">其他职业证书</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section10">个人兴趣及技</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section11">家庭信息</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section12">兵役信息</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section13">个人人事档案</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section14">入职资料上传</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="col-sm-10" id="content">
           ......
           //The code below is related to popups
           <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
             <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-7 control-label" style="text-align: left"><@spring.message "军官证书扫描件"/>:</label>
                <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" style="text-align: left">
                  <a href="#" onclick="openAttachmentWin('XXENTRY_OFFICER_CERTIFICATE')">
                    <i>附件上传</i>
                  </a>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="form-group" id="attachmentWindow1"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: SO Snippet Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS,The system was so huge, so much of it was wrapped up, I couldn’t really paste it in, so I had to pick the code that was most relevant to the problem